# What is `docker-credential-desktop`?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

On my MacBook Pro running macOS Big Sur, I have the following Docker [credentials helpers](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers) installed:

```
% docker-credential-[TAB]
docker-credential-desktop      docker-credential-ecr-login    docker-credential-osxkeychain
```

I don't remember installing `docker-credential-desktop` and `docker-credential-osxkeychain` so it must have got installed when I installed Docker Desktop.

I know about the `docker-credential-ecr-login` and `docker-credential-osxkeychain`, but I couldn't find any documentation on `docker-credential-desktop`. [Many people are wondering about this too](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/149). I assume it's something to do specifically with [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop).

Running `docker-credential-desktop list` gives the same output as `docker-credential-osxkeychain list`, which is what [some](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/149#issuecomment-712250356) [users](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/149#issuecomment-742484470) found on GitHub found as well.

```
% docker-credential-desktop list
{"https://<account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com":"AWS"}
% docker-credential-osxkeychain list 
{"https://<account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com":"AWS"}
```

This leads me to think that `docker-credential-desktop` is just a wrapper around `docker-credential-osxkeychain`. However, looking at the actual binary, the `docker-credential-desktop` is 14M compared to 2.8M for `docker-credential-osxkeychain`.

```
% ls -ahl /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-credential-*
-rwxr-xr-x  1   14M Sep  5 16:14 docker-credential-desktop
-rwxr-xr-x  1   10M Sep  5 16:14 docker-credential-ecr-login
-rwxr-xr-x  1  2.8M Jul  7 10:59 docker-credential-osxkeychain
```

**So what is the `docker-credential-desktop` credential helper?** Why is `docker-credential-osxkeychain` insufficient?

Answer (score -1):

Docker credential helpers are tools that help Docker CLI securely store and retrieve authentication information for container registries

The specific credential helper used by Docker Desktop depends on the operating system:

On macOS, the default credential helper is `docker-credential-osxkeychain`.
On Windows, it's `docker-credential-wincred` or `docker-credential-desktop`.
On Linux, it can be `docker-credential-secretservice`, `docker-credential-gnome-keyring`, or `docker-credential-desktop`.
Now, let's focus on why `docker-credential-osxkeychain` might be considered insufficient on `macOS`.

Docker Credential Helpers on macOS:
docker-credential-osxkeychain:

This is the default credential helper on macOS.
It stores Docker credentials in the macOS Keychain, providing a secure storage mechanism.
It works well for many users and environments.
docker-credential-desktop on `macOS`:

docker-credential-desktop is introduced to address some issues or limitations that users might face with the default credential helper.
It is designed to offer additional flexibility or features based on user needs.